# include ruby modules without the include statement - how is this implemented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, devise

following code is generated by devise.
How can we just use "devise" here to include the modules in my User class.
How is the devise recognized here ?
I don't see any include statement here. Is it included in the ActiveRecord ?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and     :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Answer (score 3):

When you load Devise (probably via a Rails initializer), it extends the ActiveRecord::Base class with Devise::Model

[See it in the devise source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7ba37b5dc034fdd74fc63464dd6fec65a877d3ca/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb#L42).

```
ActiveRecord::Base.extend Devise::Models
```